# Parsing nested NSDictionary into JSON, and POST to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

So I'm having this issue where my server requests a JSON in the format :

```
{
  "offers" : [
  ],
  "branch_id" : 186,
  "payment_method" : "C",
  "cash_amount" : 17,
  "car_model" : "",
  "coupon_id" : 0,
  "car_color" : "",
  "timer" : 299,
  "brand_id" : 48,
  "items" : [
    {
      "id" : 1952,
      "options" : {
        "369" : [
          1044
        ],
        "370" : [
          1045
        ]
      },
      "quantity" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

This format requires some nested NSDiconary & Arrays, which is no issue for me, but when I create this format and send it to the server, this is what I get :

```
[Object: null prototype] {
    branch_id: '186',
    brand_id: '48',
    car_color: '',
    car_model: '',
    cash_amount: '18',
    coupon_id: '0',
    'items[][id]': '1952',
    'items[][options][369][]': '1044',
    'items[][options][370][]': '1046',
    'items[][quantity]': '1',
    payment_method: 'C',
    timer: '299'
}
```

I tried to parse it using :

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalOrder options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonOrder = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but I still get a wrong format like :

```
[Object: null prototype] {
branch_id: '186',
brand_id: '48',
car_color: '',
car_model: '',
cash_amount: '36',
coupon_id: '0',
'items[]': '{\n' +
'    id = 1952;\n' +
'    options =     {\n' +
'        369 =         (\n' +
'            1044\n' +
'        );\n' +
'        370 =         (\n' +
'            1046\n' +
'        );\n' +
'    };\n' +
'    quantity = 2;\n' +
'}',
payment_method: 'C',
timer: '299'
}
```

where is the error ? is it a client-side, or parsing error on the server-side?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but never *prettyPrint* data which is sent to a server. The server doesn't care at all.

Comment: Seing the extra `\n`, I also am thinking about the prettyPrinted. But it would mean that the parsing on your server is a little strange.

Comment: what do you mean by pretty print ?

Comment: We mean the option `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`. Pass no options.

Comment: You should test sending JSON you know is valid (such as that from your example) from a tool like Postman or curl. If your server understands it correctly, then the issue is on the client side, if you get a similar incorrect result, you have taken the client out of the equation, so you know it's a server side issue.